# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in Woocommerce Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Today i noticed this strange error into [my Woocommerce site](http://moodmintdesign.com). When try to checkout, fill all data, and press on Paypal button (I use Paypal as payment gateway), i get this error into top:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

[image]

What i tryed to resolve:

1. Disabled all plugins to identify conflict between -> No luck
2. Tryed to check Inspect Element, and see this warning:

   Unable to fix malformed JSON checkout.min.js:1

Also checked error_log into my server, and there have this error:

```
[18-Apr-2018 17:04:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_order_number() on boolean in /home/moodmint/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php on line 77
```

I use Woocommerce 3.3.5, and WooPress theme.

Comment: Can you get the JSON and print it?

Comment: No, how to do that?

Comment: Educated guess: you're probably getting an HTML response, not a JSON response.

Comment: I just shares what i get as responce.. Dont know too much.. For that i provided URL into post, so someone who can help can see himself.

Comment: Check what happens in plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php on line 77 try printing the suppoused json.